# The entity type ApplicationRole is not part of the model for the current context. This is not duplicated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

First of all, there are a lot of questions like that but this is not duplicated because my code is really diffirent than other ones.

I want to implement a membership using ***Asp.net MVC Identity***. But I can not ged ride of this error. Let's look at the codes:

**IdentityStratup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Login.Models;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Login.App_Start.Startup))]

namespace Login.App_Start
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });

            app.CreatePerOwinContext(MyDbContext.Create);

        }
    }
}
```

**Under Identity Folder -> *ApplicationRole.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace Login.Identity
{
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ApplicationRole ()
        {

        }

        public ApplicationRole (string roleName, string description) : base(roleName)
        {
            this.Description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

**Under Identity Folder -> *ApplicationUser.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace Login.Identity
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Login.cs in Models folder**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Login.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?=[a-zA-Z])[-\w.]{0,23}([a-zA-Z\d]|(?<![-.])_)$")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Remember Me")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Register.cs in Models folder**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Login.Models
{
    public class Register
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?=[a-zA-Z])[-\w.]{0,23}([a-zA-Z\d]|(?<![-.])_)$")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$")]
        [Compare("Password")]
        public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Global.asasx**

```
using Login.Identity;
using Login.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Login
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
            RoleStore<ApplicationRole> roleStore = new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(db);
            RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole>(roleStore);



                if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
                {
                    ApplicationRole adminRole = new ApplicationRole("Admin", "System Admnistrator");
                    roleManager.Create(adminRole);
                }

                if (!roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
                {
                    ApplicationRole userRole = new ApplicationRole("User", "System Contraint User");
                    roleManager.Create(userRole);
                }


        }
    }
}
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
using Login.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Login.Models
{
    public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("name=LoginDBContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }

        public static MyDbContext Create()
        {
            return new MyDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

I gave you the full of application. I could not resolve this problem mentioned on the title of this question. When I run the application throws that exeption in the global.asasx file right in this line of the code
 `if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))`. What do you think about this issue ?

Comment: I tried your advice but not working. Thank you @haim770 3

Comment: Your code maybe different, but the problem is the same as in the other questions. Basically this error says either your database does not have a table to store roles or migrations don't know about this table. Create create new migration see what is added in the migration, run the migration on the db.

Comment: Absolutely you are right. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a context named `LoginDBContext`, however your Identity DB Context is named `MyDbContext`

Change the third line of the `Application_Start` to

```
      MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
```

Comment: You are right but I did forget to change that line. I did your advice but no it is not working. Thank you.

Comment: DO the following:
Open the package manager console, run the enable-migrations command followed by add-migration -name Initial, then you should find a new class called Configurations inside a folder called Migration, in this class there is a method called Seed, move the code that add the roles into this method and try again

Comment: When I tried to Enable migrations I get this error "eating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel."

Comment: Yes dear, you have to use code first and asp.net identity is based on code first not DB first.